# What is the index of a specific array when using .contains

Tags: vb.net

I am using .net vb (framework 2.0) and I need to find the index of the array (location in the array).

I have an array (string) called databases

I don't want to loop through all the array items to find the location(index) of a specific search. So I am using the .contains; but when the search string is found how can I know it's location(index) in the array.

```
 if Databases.contains("SearchString") then
        'now show the index (Location) array containing the search string 
        'Please insert code
    end if
```

Comment: `.contains` means that it appears somewhere in the array without any specifics - it returns a boolean instead of an index. If you want a specific index, you need to iterate the array.

Comment: So without an iterate it's not possible :(

Comment: Did you read my comment? `.contains` returns true or false, which means there is no way to determine an index.

Comment: I did a web search for *"vb.net find index of element in array"* and one of the very first results was another SO thread that provided the answer. You should not be asking questions that you can find the answer to on the web or have already been asked and answered on this site. If you're not searching thoroughly first, you're not doing your due diligence.

Comment: You can use [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: `Array.IndexOf(Databases, "SearchString")` will return -1 if the array doesn't contain `"SearchString"` and will return the index of the element otherwise. So, no need to use `Contains()`.

Comment: Or if you want to get the index of the element that _contains_ the search string, you may use `Array.FindIndex(Databases, Function(s) s.Contains("SearchString"))`.

Comment: Yes ! Array.FindIndex(Databases, Function(s) s.Contains("SearchString")) --> did it for me . . .